# Allowing User To Change Start-Up Form (User Control)

Tags: controls

I am developing a software in which a user can control and monitor their system. As a default, a welcome screen pops up and welcomes the user. However, I want them to have the option to skip it. 
Here is the code I am trying to work with as I found on another form, but no luck. Any solutions?

[Link to Abel Software Website](http://abelsoftware.webs.com)

```css
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            My.Application.MainForm = Form1
        End If
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

[The Welcome Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdUZ7.jpg)